# Carrierwave doesn't save cache in Google cloud storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, fog

I have a form with input fields and button for upload image in Google cloud storage (GCS). If i enter not valid values this form will be render. After rendering image miss. I use Carrierwave and Fog/Google. I have tried to add cache but it doesn't help. Image saves in GCS, image_cache doesn't save, but URL to cache file present in html code.
Uploader:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

# Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
# include CarrierWave::RMagick
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
process resize_to_fit: [500, 500]

# Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
# storage :file
if Rails.env.development?
  #storage :file
  def store_dir
    Rails.root + "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    Rails.root + "uploads/tmp/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

else
  #storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "uploads/tmp/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
# Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
# This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:

# Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
def default_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path([version_name, 'form-default.png'].compact.join('_'))
end
```

Initializer:

```
require 'carrierwave/storage/file'
require 'carrierwave/storage/fog'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if not Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:                         'Google',
      google_storage_access_key_id:     ENV['GSASAK'],
      google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV['GSSAK'],
      persistent:                       false
    }
    config.fog_directory = 'my-bucket'
    config.asset_host     = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket'
    config.fog_public = true
  else
    config.storage = :file
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% if @form.photo? %>
  <div class="photo-new"><img src= <%= @form.photo_url %> id="output"/></div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="photo-new"><img id="output"/></div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="container" style="background-color: #e0e0e0" title="Upload photo of your product">
    <label for="upload" class="uploadButton">UPLOAD PHOTO</label>
    <%= f.hidden_field :photo_cache %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo, id: "upload", onchange: "loadFile(event)" %>
```

Model:

```
class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
```

Controller (permit params):

```
def form_params
  params.require(:form).permit!
end
```

Comment: I have done this issue. Solution is here [github](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku)